# How to use ***sprintf_s*** for linux C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I am trying a Create a Linux C++ project using the same header and `.cpp` files from a Windows C++ project using Visual Studio. I am using `sprintf_s` to convert string to array.

But when I port the same code to Linux, `sprintf_s` is showing error. Is there any other replacement for `sprintf_s`?

Is that ok to use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf_s` ?

```
#if _WINDLL
        sprintf_s(DestinationArray, SourceString.c_str()); //Syntax using sprintf_s for Windows
#else

        snprintf(DestinationArray, SourceString.length(), SourceString.c_str()); //syntax using snprintf For Linux

#endif
```

Is the above syntax correct? I am new to C++ . Please help.

Comment: afaik there is `sprintf_s` in C but not in C++, C++ has `std::string` so it does not need a mechanism to safely pass the size of a string that urgently

Comment: sprintf_s is a C function. It doesn't know what a C++ string is, so don't feed it C++ strings.

Comment: If you are using C++, why not use the C++ stream tools?

Comment: Regardless of availability, using `sprintf_s` here looks like the wrong tool, why don't you use `strncpy`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other replacement for sprintf_s?

There is `std::snprintf`. Even better, you could use `std::string` and iostreams.

> Is that ok to use snprintf instead of sprintf_s ?

`std::snprintf` is a replacement for `sprintf_s`. However, Passing the source string size as the second argument is wrong. You're supposed to pass the size of the destination buffer instead.

Furthermore, you're misusing `sprintf_s` in the first place. You should never use non-constant format string. It appears that you're attempting to simple copy a string. For that purpose, there is for example `strlcpy` (not standard in C++, but exists in BSD and Linux).

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf_s` passes the size of `DestinationArray`, not SourceString. Also, don't pass arbitrary strings as format string, that's how you get format string exploits.

A more correct formulation:

```
#if _WINDLL
        sprintf_s(DestinationArray, "%s", SourceString.c_str()); //Syntax using sprintf_s for Windows
#else
        snprintf(DestinationArray, sizeof(DestinationArray), "%s",  SourceString.c_str()); //syntax using snprintf For Linux
#endif
```

Or you can define `sprintf_s` for Linux as a macro:

```
#define sprintf_s(buf, ...) snprintf((buf), sizeof(buf), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: the `#define` solution really rocks!